# iPhone Simulator producing different XCode visual content

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

In XCode I've created a tabbed application.

On one of tabs I've dragged in a table view and set the content to static. As you can see below in the first screenshot there are 2 tables. These are exactly how I want them to look.

XCode:

[image]

Now I run the simulator and this is presented to me:

Simulator:

[image]

If anyone could tell me why this is happening I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen when ran on a real device?

Comment: Sadly I cannot test that at the moment as I'm waiting for my certificate. Although I'm 99% sure this is something I've done rather than a problem with the si... I forgot to say I'm also running this on a preview version of the latest XCode. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Possible. Are you running the latest preview?

Comment: @0x7fffffff I'm running: Version 5.0 (5A11314m)

Comment: That definitely is a possibility. You should move this to the Aplpe forums and see if they know. I think the pre-release stuff is under NDA, so you probably won't get much help here. And it also looks like you got iOS 7 o that simulator, so definitely NDA.